# Calculating discountmargin using flat yield

Tags: fixed-income, bond, floating-rate

How do you calculate the discount margin of a floating rate bond using flat yield? What is the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

[image]
[image]

Another DM variant is this:
[image]

Source:

[image]

This document has numerical examples.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I am a co-author of that paper. You may want to check out FinancePy which is a beta version of a finance library where I have implemented the code for calculating the discount margin. Here is an example Jupyter notebook that reproduces (almost exactly) a Bloomberg example.

https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/blob/master/notebooks/products/bonds/FINBONDFRN_CitigroupExample.ipynb

The underlying code is in

https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/blob/master/financepy/products/bonds/FinBondFRN.py

Contact me at quant@financepy.com if you have any issues or questions regarding FinancePy.

Comment: Can your library also be used for bonds with irregular cashflows? Eg if I have modelled the cashflows from an ABS / RMBS / bespoke investment separately (I don't want your library to do that), can I use your library to calculate the DM of those cashflows?

Comment: It should be possible - you would need to set the internal date and flow schedule (one is a list of dates and the other is a list of floats) - as everything is open in Python this should be possible. Can you add this as a request on github issues https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/issues and I can see if I can add a method which makes it easier to do and has some validation checks. Or contact me via quant@financepy.com

Comment: Could you elaborate on what $L_{\text{stub}}$ is or how it is calculated?