Do z-spreads and quoted margins move in sync?
Consider a floating bond with unit face value that pays $L_t + s$ at time $t$, where $L_t$ is some reference-rate at time $t$ and $s$ is a spread.
The $z$-spread is the value $z$ such that $P = \sum (L_t + s) (r_t + z)^{-t}$ where $P$ is the price of the bond and $r_t$ is the zero rate for time $t$.
My question is about $s$ and $z$.
Is there a meaningful relationship between these?
For example, it would seem intuitive to me that they exactly offset each other, i.e. if a bond has $z = 0, s = s$, then if it were to suddenly set $s = 0$, its $z$ would jump to $s$ (approximately). And vice-versa. And they would sort of "meet in the middle".
Is this true?

For almost all floaters, the spread $s$ is set at issuance and doesn't change.
(Actually, there are rare exceptions that we'll ignore - $s$ change triggered by the issuer's agency credit rating or ESG score changes, step-up floaters where $s$ changes according to a schedule set at issuance. In some markets they use gearing instead of spread.)
When a new bond is issued, the originator figures out the $s$, close to the issuer's CDS spread - the lowest $s$ that will entice enough investors to buy the desired amount of bond at price close to par. Once $s$ is set, it doesn't change.
In contrast, the Z-spread (and discount margin) are calculated from a given price. If you plug in price close to / above / below par, then you will get a Z-spread (and DM) close to / below / above $s$.

That's assuming that you're calculating the Z-spread over the same curve used for the fixings, right?  If one had a bond paying Euribor and wanted to calculate the Z-spread over the risk-free ESTR curve, the basis between the two curves would also get into play.

Thanks @LuigiBallabio yes you're right, there's this added wrinkle - any basis between the discount curve and the projection curve would contribute to the "close to" not being exact :)

In currencies other than EUR as well, some (rare) floaters reset from indices even more different from that of the discount curve, such T-bills or 10Y treasuries. Then there's that basis.

But at issuance, there is a link, no?
If $s$ is set so that it sells a par, then they must exactly set $s$ such that $DM = 0$ .. otherwise it wouldn't sell at par.
So that's what I mean by them offsetting each other.
Imagine I issue a bond at $s$ that sells at par, then $DM = 0$.
Then imagine tomorrow the $DM$ rises to $200bps$ and I issue ANOTHER bond. Then what I mean by "moving in sync" is that this other bond I issue must be issued with $s = s_0 + 200bps$where $s_0$ is the spread of the first bond.

@JakcieJnr I don't think that when a bond trades at par, and its $s$ is non-zero, then DM is 0. DM is like Z spread. Please look at https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60210

Exaggerating the volatility :), and ignoring some details, suppose that in week 1, the issuer's CDS spread is 200 bps, and the issuer sells at par floating rate note A, paying index + 200 bps. Its Z spread is 200 now. In week 2 some bad news appear about the issuer, so its CDS sprrad and Z spread of its outstanding bonds widen to 300 bps. Bond A trades below par. The issuer sells at par new frn B paying index + 300 bps. In week 3, the CDS and Z spreads tighten to 100 bps, so A trades above par, and B trades above A in the secondary markets.
